# React hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component error

Tags: html, reactjs

I have the following react script, and I am trying to call the 'HandleListing' function as soon as the app opens. It then should detect what the user is saying, print it out on screen, and display the corresponding image. Below is my code:

```
import SpeechRecognition, {useSpeechRecognition} from "react-speech-recognition";
import map from "./map.jpeg";
import mapClosed from "./map-closed.jpeg";
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

let transcript;
function HandleListing() {
  SpeechRecognition.startListening({
    continuous: true,
  });
  transcript = useSpeechRecognition();
}

const App = () => (
  HandleListing(),
  (
    <div>
      {transcript && <div>{transcript}</div>}
      {transcript == "hello" && (
        <ImageBackground source={map}>
        </ImageBackground>
      )}
      {transcript != "hello" && (
        <ImageBackground
          source={mapClosed}
        ></ImageBackground>
      )}
    </div>
  )
);

export default App;
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
```

I am very new to react, so am unsure what I am doing wrong, could anyone assist please? thanks

Comment: I'd suspect this is because `useSpeechRecognition()` is a custom hook (usually denoted by the "use" prefix). If so, you'll need to restructure your code to put it in a function component. Here's some context on that: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#building-your-own-hooks

Comment: Thank you @Serlite. I don't suppose you could provide an example of how I would do that with my code? I seem to be getting confused. Thank you

Comment: I see you've gotten an answer for this, which probably gives you enough to work with. I'd advise making sure you work through the docs if you haven't already - at least the Main Concepts and the Hooks sections so you can brush up on anything you're unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggest react hook must only be initialize in react components (which is within the `const APP =() => {}`), u should not wrap it in a function or outside the function components, same goes to every other hooks, useState(), useEffect() and etc.

```
const App = () => {
 let transcript = useSpeechRecognition()
 
 function Listening () {
   SpeechRecognition.startListening({
     continous : true
   }) 
 }

  (
   ...
  )

}
```